# How to expand a randomHuman constructor to take two types of objects?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

I am a java-noob as I recently started to learn in a course.
I have created a class:Humans which have ability to store their name and age, and also a subclass Students which extends Humans and adds the Year they began there studies.
I have constructed a randomHuman constructor where I call it(in my main class) and create a list with the humans(with random name and age).
My problem is when i want to random 5 human non-students and 5 students and create this list, I'm not sure how to find out what type of object is sent to the random constructor, so i know if i should give it a year or not. And what type to tell the constructor to return.

I am sorry that this turned into an essay, but if anyone would be so kind to help then I would greatly appreciate it.

**TLDR;** How to expand a randomHuman constructor to take two types of objects?

Here is my main class:

> > public class Main {
> >         public static void main(String []args){
>
> ```
> Human newHuman = new Human( 18, "Tommy");
> System.out.println("Age: " + newHuman.getAge());
> System.out.println("Name: " + newHuman.getName());
> System.out.println(newHuman.toString());
>
> Human putte = new Human (25,"Putte");
> System.out.println(putte);
> //Varför blir det så?
> //kanske lokal variabel
>
> //Array RandomHumans
> System.out.println(" ");
> System.out.println("Array Human");
> ArrayList<Human> myAl = new ArrayList();
>
> for(int i = 0; i<15; i++){
>     Human xx =Human.randomHuman();
>     myAl.add(xx);
> }
> //Array RandomFysiker
> for(int j = 0; j<myAl.size(); j++){
>    Human var = myAl.get(j);
>     System.out.println(var.toString());
> }
>
> System.out.println(" ");
> System.out.println("Array Fysiker");
> ArrayList<Fysiker> myAl2 = new ArrayList();
> //puts the Fysiker in an array
> for(int i = 0; i<15; i++){
>     Fysiker xx =Fysiker.randomHuman();
>     myAl2.add(xx);
> }
> //prints teh array
> for(int j = 0; j<myAl2.size(); j++){
>    Fysiker var = myAl2.get(j);
>     System.out.println(var.toString());
> }
> ```
>
> } 
>   }

and my Human class:

```
public class Human {
    public String name;
    public int age;

    Human(int ageIn, String nameIn){ //Constructor
    age=ageIn;
    name=nameIn;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: " + getName() +"," + " Age: " + getAge();
    }


        //Random human
    // Behöver ändra konstruktorn så att den kan kolla
    // om objectet är Fysiker eller Human och sedan,
    // Behandla dom olika
    //Problem1: Hur kollar man? Föreslag if(obj instanceof Fysiker), men vad ska jag ha som obj
    //Problem2: Vilken returtyp ska man då ha?
    public static Human randomHuman(){
        String[] anArrayOfStrings={"Tom", "Jon", "Chris","Julian","Roberto","Sam","Lisa","Roxanne","Rebecca","Anton","Johannes","Antonella","Bianca"};
        int randomAge = (int) (100*Math.random());
        String randomName = anArrayOfStrings[(int)(Math.random()*anArrayOfStrings.length)];
        int RandomYear = (int) (Math.random()*(2013-1932) + 1932);
//        if(xx instanceof Fysiker){
//            
//        }
        return new Human(randomAge,randomName);
    }    
}
```

and the subclass Fysiker(aka student):

```
/**
 *
 * @author Julian
 */

public class Fysiker extends Human{
    public int schoolYear;

    public Fysiker(int startYear,int ageIn, String nameIn){
        super(ageIn, nameIn);
        if (age>15){
            if (startYear>2013){
            } else if (startYear<1932){
            } else {
                schoolYear = startYear;
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
    public int getYear(){
        return schoolYear;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() +","+" Startyear: " +getYear();
    }
}
```

Comment: um, your `randomHuman` is **not** a constructor but a static factory **method**. There's a big difference between constructors and methods.

Comment: Myself, I'd use a `java.util.Random` object and call its `nextBoolean()`. If it's true, create one type of Human and if false create the other type.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Oh, It is supposed to be a constructor which calls upon the original constructor. I'll read up on it right away!
so, Human xx=new Human(age,name)
if(xx.nextBoolean()){
{else
have i understood that correctly?
How can I get the variable xx in the Human class if I create it in the Main class. As you see in my code I do Human xx=new Human() in the main class, and I want to do the nextBoolean() in the Human class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your `randomHuman()` method, as mentioned in the comments, is not a constructor at all. It's a static factory method, although I'm sure you're not aware of what that means as yet.

Basically, a constructor is not a method at all and doesn't have a return type. What a constructor does is provide an initialization for a new instance of the class, created by using `new`, although it can do things that don't strictly initiate the fields of that object.

A method, in contrast, can return something. And in your particular case, the last line actually tells you exactly what it returns - it's calling `new` for the class `Human`, so it will return an object of class `Human`, never a `Student`.

In fact, the class `Human` is not aware of the class `Student`. In principle, you could write a subclass for a class, years after the parent class has been written. Parent classes don't need to know about their descendents. They just decide what they allow those descendents to change and what they don't allow them to change.

You could, in theory, put a method in `Human` that creates a `Student` instance. But I'm pretty sure that's not needed in the current situation.

What you probably want to do is fill a list of humans outside the definition of either `Human` or `Student`. Filling a random list is probably not part of "being a human" or "being a student" is all about, so you should just do it in your `Main` class, calling `new Human()` or `new Student()` as you wish and filling them as appropriate. Since you know which `new` you called, you also know whether or not to use a random year.

You could do it in a static method in your `Main` class, to signify that this is something you do for testing, and not really part of the logic of either a `Human` or a `Student`.

As for being able to tell which object you now got from the list - you can do that with `instanceof`. But you'll also need to typecast it to `Student` if you want to access its `getYear()` method.

However - and this is the neat thing about polymorphism - if you just call the `toString()` method, and don't even check the type of the object, you'll get it with the year if it's really a `Student` object, and without it if it's a plain `Human` object.

---

Let's assume your teachers actually want you to extend the `randomHuman` method so that it sometimes gives `Human` instances, and sometimes `Students`. When it gives `Student`, it should of course provide it with a year.

As I said above, this is called *Tight Coupling* between parent and subclass, and is not recommended. If I wanted to build another human subclass, such as `Politician`, I'd have to call you and ask you to release a new version of `Human` that also sometimes gives random `Politician`s. So, under protest, I'll explain how to do it.

Your existing function is:

```
public static Human randomHuman(){
        String[] anArrayOfStrings={"Tom", "Jon", "Chris","Julian","Roberto","Sam","Lisa","Roxanne","Rebecca","Anton","Johannes","Antonella","Bianca"};
        int randomAge = (int) (100*Math.random());
        String randomName = anArrayOfStrings[(int)(Math.random()*anArrayOfStrings.length)];
        int RandomYear = (int) (Math.random()*(2013-1932) + 1932);
//        if(xx instanceof Fysiker){
//            
//        }
        return new Human(randomAge,randomName);
    }
```

We change it like so:

```
public static Human randomHuman(){
    String[] anArrayOfStrings={"Tom", "Jon", "Chris","Julian","Roberto","Sam","Lisa","Roxanne","Rebecca","Anton","Johannes","Antonella","Bianca"};
    int randomAge = (int) (100*Math.random());
    String randomName = anArrayOfStrings[(int)(Math.random()*anArrayOfStrings.length)];

    Human result = null;

    if ( Math.random() < 0.5 ) {
        // With a probability of 50%, create a plain human
        result = new Human( randomAge, randomName );
    } else {
        // Create a student. Start by calculating a random year.
        int randomYear = (int) (Math.random()*(2013-1932) + 1932);
        result = new Fysiker( randomYear, randomAge, randomName );
    }

    return result;

}
```

So, you decide that you want to make a plain human, and within the scope of that decision, you create it with `new Human(...)` and assign to the `result` variable.

If you decide to make a student, within the scope of that decision, you calculate a random year, and create it with `new Fysiker()`. You can assign it to the variable `result` because polymorphically, it's `Human`. But in reality, internally, it's a Student.

You return the `result` variable, which may contain either a `Human` or a `Student` at this point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a great response and a free lesson!
What you are talking about seems like an easier way around it, for sure.

The only problem is that the task itself clearly states that I have to expand the previous randomHuman()Method (not constructor), to create a random year if the person is a student.
I will do as you said and send in 5 new Human() and 5 new Student() from the main class. but in the RandomHuman(), what would be the objective name. (If you understand me, im not sure how to express myself here).

Comment: Ex:
If I write the following in my main class: Human xx = Human.randomHuman(), and Student xx = Student.RandomHuman().

Then my plan was to do the following i nthe randomHuman method:

if(xx instanceof Human){
create human
}else{
create student
}
but is xx not the object in this case?
I apologize, but I can't seem to get space between my lines. It's horrible for the eyes

Comment: It doesn't exist before you call `randomHuman()`. Moreover, you cannot declare it in your main once as `Human` and once as `Student` in the same block. Why don't you write the **exact** definition of your exercise in your question? The way you put it it's a very odd requirement.

Comment: I did not add it in the question as it is written in swedish and overall it's rather long, therefore i tried to only explain the part which I am stuck on. Would it be possible to have a randomHuman() method in the subclass Student which inhertiance from randomHuman() but also adds the part to have a year in it?

Comment: I can do my best to translate it properly if you want, also if I am to much of an hassle then I'll certainly understand

Comment: In fact, you can't override a static method. I suspect perhaps they wanted you to extend the actual `randomHuman` method in `Human` to supply random `Student`s as well, although this is not good practice, as I said. But I can't really determine what exactly they wanted without the exercise, and if it requires translation, it's a problem because meaning can be lost. Anyway, one thing is sure, you can't determine what the object is until you have created it. Not just the reference to it, the object itself.

Comment: Your suspision is correct, after the creation of the Human class, I was to create a subclass Student (Fysiker in my case), which inheritance the methods but also adds the year. Then expand the toString() method which works so neatily as you explained withpolymorphism. Then the part which I am stuck on: It says: expand the random constructor(they call it a constructor which is ment to call upon the original constructor) to also create a random year.

Comment: OK, then. I edited my answer to show you how to do that.

Comment: Lovely, I give you my best of graditute and I will certainly take your protest as my own and bring it to my teachers.
Now it I am to create 5 of each and a 50% chance, but I am certain I can take it from here. Thank you very much sir, I'm sorry I dont have the rep to upvote your comments.

Comment: You know that you can't control the actual number of each that this creates. Call it 10 times, it may give you 7 Humans and 3 Students. Call it 10 more times, it may give you  4 Humans and 6 Students. It's 50% probability, but probability meets reality only for very large numbers. And just to remind you, though you cannot vote, you're still allowed to accept any of the answers you got.

Answer (score 0):

For determining what type the object instance is use either `object instanceof class` or `object.getClass().equals(Clazz.getSimpleName())`

For return type just use the superClass (or interface). You can always cast it to the child if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
In my case, where i do: Human xx=new Human.randomHuman() in the main class.

Would then the object be xx? Or have I got that wrong?

Comment: Yes, the object would be xx so you would have something `if (xx isntanceof SomeClass)`...

Comment: Okay, wonderful. I understand how it works and it would have been fairly easy if I had it all under the same class. but the objext xx is defined in the main class. Therefore im not able to use that if statement in the Human class. It says: Cannot find symbol

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create 5 class of each you need a boolean in the method declaration and call it 5 times each to be sure u will have 5 instances of each class.

```
    public static Human randomHuman(boolean isHuman){
```

If this is not important u can add a random boolean and then call the constructor:

```
boolean isHuman = Math.random() < 0.5;
    if(!isHuman){
        int RandomYear = (int) (Math.random()*(2013-1932) + 1932);
        // create student
    } else {
        // create human
    }
```